# Troubles with switching from babel6 to babel7: Property name expected type of string but got null at Array.forEach ()

Tags: redux, babeljs

I just updated Babel6 to Babel7 with all of the necessary packages but can't resolve how to make `babel.config.js` correctly getting one or another error depending on the specified `Babel7` plugins. Here is how my `babel.config.js` looks like:

```
module.exports = {    
  "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          "@babel/preset-react"
        ],  
        "plugins": [
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
          "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
          "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
          "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node",
          "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from"
        ]   
      }   
    },  
    "plugins": [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from",
      "babel-plugin-dynamic-import-node",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      "@babel/plugin-transform-regenerator",
      "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import",
      [   
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators",
        {   
          "legacy": true
        }   
      ],  
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread",
      "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
      [   
        "babel-plugin-styled-components",
        {   
          "displayName": true
        }   
      ],  
      [   
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver",
        {   
          "root": [
            "./"
          ],  
          "extensions": [
            ".js",
            ".jsx",
            ".css"
          ],
          "alias": {
            "shared": "./shared/",
            "pages": "./pages/",
            "gtex-d3": "./node_modules/gtex-d3/"
          }
        }
      ]
    ],
    "presets": [
      "@babel/preset-react",
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "modules": false
        }
      ]
    ]
}
```

So, with such configs I am getting the error:

> TypeError: (0 , _typeof2.default) is not a function

Here I found a probable solution:

https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/6879

Remove `"@babel/preset-env"`. So, after removing it I am getting an error in one of the `node_modules` package (which may mean that `@babel/preset-env` is needed to avoid that...):

> ./node_modules/igv/dist/igv.esm.js
>   Module build failed: TypeError: /Users/vlasenkona/Desktop/gris-seqr2/ui/node_modules/igv/dist/igv.esm.js: Property name expected type of string but got null
>       at Array.forEach ()

If I remove `"@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs"` instead I will get another error:

> ./node_modules/semantic-ui-react/dist/es/modules/Dropdown/Dropdown.js
>   1002:14-23 "export 'default' (imported as 'PropTypes') was not found in 'prop-types'

Which is happening because the removed `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` is needed for that. So, from these `3` errors it seems to me that the second should be fixed and there is a thread:

https://github.com/alanbsmith/babel-plugin-react-add-property/issues/3

And it is not solved, so I am stuck. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

1. `npm install --save-dev @babel/plugin-transform-destructuring`
2. `. babelrc 
   { "plugins": [ ["@babel/plugin-transform-destructuring", { "useBuiltIns": true }] ] }`